# Is it possible to use AES Algorithm to encrypt message payload in Mulesoft

Tags: aes, mulesoft

We need to encrypt the payload with AES Algorithm using 32 chars Key in Mulesoft.

Do we have the option to implement it like we have JCE and PGP in Crypto module. How to encrypt using AES. And also to decrypt it manually after the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mule Cryptography Module to encrypt/decrypt payñoadd with a JCE configuration: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/cryptography-jce. Select AES as the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @aled. Is it possible to give dynamic password and no keystore file?

Comment: PBE methods don't require a key. Note that it is not the same as using plain AES as just a symmetric algorithm. There is a KB with an example in MuleSoft Help Center: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-implement-JCE-Cryptography-PBE-Password-Based-Encryption-in-Mule-4

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this MuleSoft knowledge base article on [How to implement asymmetric Key Based Encryption using JCE Cryptography in Mule 4](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-implement-asymmetric-Key-Based-Encryption-using-JCE-Cryptography-in-Mule-4)

The showcased instance employs the RSA algorithm for encryption and decryption, yet you have the option to experiment with alternative algorithms such as AES as per your use case.

Please ensure to review the enclosed attachments containing the application jar file as an example.

Comment: Thank you @Rahat Rajdev, is it possible to give dynamic password?

Comment: Note that AES is a symmetric encryption algorithm.